# extract a line from text file python

Tags: python, text

Hi I am new to python and dont really know where to start, so here goes

i have the below portion of a text file text file the file is much longer and i want to pick out some information from it if a line in the file begins with "Error" then i want to print that information in another text file

```
1 warning message 
Warning 1 - Loop End (SGLoopControl2) - errors were encountered during run
2 error messages
Error 1 - 0952 RHFDShaftTorq Not Found in asd22961ck99_
Error 2 - Multi-column property values processing halted at loop iteration 2 (run failed)
```

any help much appreciated.

Comment: Where to start on stackoverflow.com is at the top of the page, at right, to make a search on some words, for example "extract text file", or in your case which is very simple "reading file", you'll obtain quantities of threads in which people were wanting to do similar things as nyou.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Error'):
            do_something_with_line(line)
```

You might also want to **strip** the line with `line.strip()`.